# How to deploy war file in apache2 in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: java, apache-httpd

I want to run my application with the help of apache2. In tomcat we will put the war files in folder webapps. I am looking something similar in apache2.

Comment: Apache2 is a web server not application, it can't run wars.

Answer (score 2):

Apache is a web server. It doesn't have a servlet/JSP engine built into it.

You can install Tomcat, which is a servlet/JSP engine, and configure Apache to forward requests for servlets and JSPs to it.

You should also know that Tomcat is not a full Java EE app server. It's a servlet/JSP engine, just a subset of Java EE. It doesn't have capabilities for EJBs or JMS. You'll have to add OpenEJB and ActiveMQ to Tomcat to get those.